# Todo app remind user of a todo item or items

Tags: angularjs, laravel, scheduled-tasks

### The Background

I'm making a simple to-do app because I'm trying to practice my company's new way of working which involves angular as a front end framework and laravel as restful api for services and other things. This is a simple app that would be on a web server like `http://mytodoapp.com`.

### The problem

How can I warn the user when he has to do something? For example, he comes, logs in and created a new todo item, which is something like `buy food for Rex after work at 5:00pm` (his dog). How can I make the app warn the user: `Hey you have to buy food for Rex!`?

### The Solution

I know I can easily make a script that everytime the user visits his dashboard or so, he should check on the todos and see which one is up, but this is pretty unpractical because let's say, the user doesn't check his app for an entire day and he totally missed he had to go to his daughters wedding, or he forgot he had to visit his sick relative in the hospital, or he has to pick up Jerry from soccer practice at 5.

Is there any other way I can automate a script to run every 5minutes? or every 10minutes? And what timespan would you consider good and efficient to run this script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your use case, does the user have to have a browser tab open to get notifications?

Comment: Not necessarily, I'm sure apps similar to this one, they send emails whenever there is a task at hand, however I'm wondering any other simple way to let the user know about his tasks

Comment: Well, different types of notifications are differently implemented. For notifications in the browser, you could have your angular app call the server in an interval and fetch new notifications. For email notifications you'd have to set up a cronjob on your server that runs a php script (or better a laravel command) that then sends an email if necessary

Comment: Cronjob? Haven't really hard of this before, let me get into that. As for browser notifications, it's probably safe to say you need a tab with the app to be opened right?

Comment: Yes, the app would have to be opened. Otherwise you'd have to develop some sort of browser extension or app.

Comment: Gotcha, but that would be very dependant to Chrome am I right? I mean I know a lot of people use it, but that's like forcing people to go to a browser they might not want to (many people use firefox over others)

Comment: Well to support the majority of users, you'd have to write extensions (or add-ons) for at least chrome and firefox and maybe safari (no idea if Internet Explorer even knows such a thing like extensions ;))